# Samba Permissions in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

Whenever a file is being created by samba user it gets the permission

```
-rwx------  1 user1 group1  0 Feb 16 16:33 file.txt
```

I want the `group1` to get `r-- or r-x` permission everytime the user1 creates a file.

This is my smb.conf

```
[samba-shared-directory]

path = /var/new_share/KRA2017
valid users = user1 , group1
guest ok = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
```

What do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `force create mode = 0640` (or 0660 - whatever you want) to your smb.conf file - the shared directory section, and reload samba (depending on your distro - `service smb reload`, `service smbd reload`, `service samba reload`, `systemctl reload smb` etc etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would add some more info.

Samba ignores the UMASK set in the system for any user hence you may need to configure Samba to use a specific UMASK.

As example you will need to use these config parms:

`create mask = 0744`

`force create mode = 000`

`create directory mask = 0755`

`force directory mode = 000`

The values are just examples and not the current ones you need.

There is an interesting article here: http://www.bodenzord.com/archives/53 which may help you understand the problem better and address it appropriately.

HTH